# golang rpc not returning when struct has a nested struct

Tags: go, rpc

**UPDATE**

moving from gob encoding to json fixed the issue. However I would still like to know why this was failing to work with gob.

so my client code looks like this

```
account := new(database.Account)

err := client.Call("AccountDb.FindAccount", "username", account)

if err != nil {
    logger.FATAL.Print(err.Error())
    return
}

logger.INFO.Print(account)
```

On the server side `AccountDb.FindAccount` looks like this

```
func (t *AccountDb) FindAccount(args *string, reply *Account) error {

    reply.Username = "this is a test"

    return nil
}
```

The struct for Account looks like this

```
type Account struct {
    Id           int
    Username     string
    Password     string
    Email        string
    Created      time.Time
    LastLoggedIn time.Time
    AccessLevel  int

    Banned struct {
        reason  string
        expires time.Time
    }
}
```

if I attempt to perform the rpc the requests starts and the server executes the procedure. However the program then hangs and the procedure does not return! If however I remove the Banned anonymous struct from the Account struct it works fine! Why is this? is there a solution to this problem?

edit
the client and server register code looks like this

Client

```
client, err = rpc.DialHTTP("tcp", "127.0.0.1:9001")

if err != nil {
    logger.FATAL.Panic(err.Error())
}
```

Server

```
defer db.Close()

account := new(database.AccountDb)
account.Database = db

rpc.Register(account)
rpc.HandleHTTP()
l, e := net.Listen("tcp", ":9001")

if e != nil {
    logger.FATAL.Fatal("listen error:", e)
}
http.Serve(l, nil)
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a secondary struct to hold the `Banned` field information?

Comment: I've just tried this now and I got the same problem

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Evidently, the gob encoder fails to marshal the RPC response because the `Banned` struct has no exported fields.  This [playground example](http://play.golang.org/p/xv91B25aAY) exhibits the error:

```
encode error: gob: type struct { reason string; expires time.Time } 
has no exported fields
```

If you export the reason/expires fields by capitalizing them, the gob round-trip works OK (see http://play.golang.org/p/YrYFsk6trQ).

The JSON encoder also requires that serialized fields are exported, but it does not return an error if a struct has none.  The decode just returns default/zero values.  Run http://play.golang.org/p/OBBkB4tPcZ and note that the `Banned` information is lost on the round-trip.

If you need to detect these kinds of errors in the `rpc` package, there are two options:

1. Edit [rpc/debug.go](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/rpc/debug.go), set the `logDebug` flag to true, and rebuild the `rpc` package, or
2. Implement a `ServerCodec` that wraps the existing implementation and logs any errors returned by `ReadRequestBody`/`WriteResponse`.

Comment: There is an issue pending for this behaviour, https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=8173